# Convert all files in a Linux directory from NITF to PNG using gdal_translate

Tags: python, gdal-translate

I have a directory called `/home/john/WAMI/WPAFB_TRAIN/` with `.txt` files that have names like:

```
20091021202517-01000100-VIS.ntf.r0
20091021202517-01000101-VIS.ntf.r0
```

I know that the code needs to say something like:

```
for something in something:                                                             
   use gdal_translate to convert the files in the directory to .png format
```

For the life of me, I can't get any of the answers to previous stackexchange questions to work.

Answer (score 8):

#### The bash way

You can try this directly in your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (Linux based system assumed from the format of the path you provided, so it probably is [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))):

```
cd /home/john/WAMI/WPAFB_TRAIN/

mkdir pngs/

for f in *.ntf.r0; do gdal_translate ${f} pngs/${f%.*}.png; done
```

But as you did not provided a sample file, it's hard to guess if the call to `gdal_translate` for those files will need to some of the [available options](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html).

The [NITF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Imagery_Transmission_Format) format seems to be in the [GDAL drivers](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/nitf.html) so it 'should' work:

[image: NITF as a GDAL driver]

Otherwise, there may be some interesting information on this github page:
https://github.com/AFRL-RY/data-unicorn-2008/blob/master/code/NITFPythonGDAL.py

#### The Python way

If you have to do it in pure [Python](https://www.python.org/), I would do something like this:

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal
from os import walk

nitf_files_direcory = '/path/to/NITFs/'
F, _, input_file_list = next(walk(nitf_files_direcory))

def convert_nitf_to_png(input_file):
    # Assuming there are always only 2 dots '.' characters in the file
    # name, create a new 'pngs' folder nearby the folder containing
    # the input files and set the absolute path name of the output file
    output_file = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(F),
        'pngs',
        input_file.split('.')[-2]+'.png'
    )
    # Get absolute path of input file
    input_file = os.path.join(F, input_file)
    input_dataset = gdal.Open(input_file)
    # Prepare output driver (see GDAL drivers documentation 
    # for a comprehensive list)
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("PNG")
    # Write to output file using driver
    driver.CreateCopy(output_file, input_dataset, 0)
    # Remove the datasets to free memory
    del(input_dataset)
    # Be verbose if needed
    print("{} file written to disk successfully.".format(output_file))

# Call your function in a loop over your files
for file in input_file_list:
    if file.endswith(".r0"):
        convert_nitf_to_png(file)
```

Comment: First, thanks very much for you response. It threw a syntax error:

Comment: for f in *.ntf.r0; do gdal_translate ${f} pngs/${f%.*}.png; done
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The arrow for the syntax arrow seems to be pointing to the *. Do you know what information that I would need to provide for you to understand why it might have thrown that error?

Comment: Hmm, you probably have trouble with the shell expansion. Can you precise what your shell actually is, and what is its version?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7 and Anaconda. Is that what is meant by shell? Please forgive my lack of experience. I'm very new at this.

Comment: Oh, I though you'd asked that from the command line. The solution I shown has to be run in your terminal. I updated the answer to be precise on that point.

Comment: Oooooh, that must be why I couldn't get other examples from Stack Exchange to work. It seems to be converting them all to png format now. I just tested one and it works. Seriously, thank you so much!

Comment: I've added a Python example, feel free to experiment with it.